# Converting Word doc to html using OpenXmlPower tool gives error: Object Reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: c#, html, ms-word

I am trying to view my document on a web page using `OpenXml`. I have searched and found the code to convert document to `html` and then display that html page to web page. I used following code.

```
string path = @"C:\Users\spadmin\Desktop\New folder\HelloHTML.docx";
string hmtlFilePath = @"C:\Users\spadmin\Desktop\New folder\HelloHTML.html";

byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
     memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
     using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
     {
         HtmlConverterSettings settings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
         {
             PageTitle = "BIA Sample",
         };

         OpenXmlPart main = doc.MainDocumentPart;
         XElement documentElement = main.GetXDocument().Root;

         XElement html = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(doc, settings); // here I got error

         File.WriteAllText(hmtlFilePath, html.ToStringNewLineOnAttributes());
     }
}
```

But this throws an error of `Object Reference Not set to an instance of an Object`.
Then I added the OpenXmlPowerTool Project to my main project and then debug the code and I found that, When I pass the `doc` to the `ConvertToHtml()` method the properties of the doc where not there. Here are the snap shots of them.
Before passing I check the `doc` properties:
[image]

When the `ConvertToHtml()` invoke i check the doc property which was as bellow:
[image]

The properties of the documents were not there in the passed object. That is why it throws error.
Can anyone help me that what am I doing wrong?
Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: No. I didn't get any solution for this. I changed the approach for the same.

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools/issues/158